# Tratamiento de array, Objectos, javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tengo lo siguiente, me llega un Json y lo reccorro con un For, la intencion es modificar algunas propiedades en este caso el status,

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    if(datos[i].id_expediente === this.id_expediente ){
      console.log("actualizo estatus");
      var valor_cambio;
     datos.splice(i, 1, {id_expediente: datos[i].id_expediente,
        demandado: datos[i].demandado,
        direccion: datos[i].direccion,
        status: "Inicio",
        fecha_asignada: datos[i].fecha_asig,
        tipo_juicio: datos[i].tipo_juicio

      });
    }
}
```

despues de este ciclo me genera lo siguiente

```
 console.log("data++->" + JSON.stringify(datos));

 [
  [
   {
  "id_expediente": "1111",
  "demandado": "Alejandra_prueba",
  "direccion": "Plan de Ayala-cdscdscds",
  "status": "Inicio",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-06-22 10:38:30",
  "tipo_juicio": "zzzzzzxxxxx"

  }
 ],
 {
"id_expediente": "123",
"demandado": "José_prueba",
"direccion": "Plan de Ayala_pp",
"status": "Asignada",
"tipo_juicio": "xxxxxxx"
},
{
"id_expediente": "1",
"demandado": "JOSE_prueba",
"direccion": "Barlovento 1",
"status": "Asignada",
"tipo_juicio": "xxxx"
}
]
```

en este ejemplo si me cambio la propiedad del status, para el expediente 1111, el problema es que me agrega corchetes([])

La intencion es generar el json sin esos corchetes, y que se vea asi

```
 [
  [//quiero eliminar este corchete
   {
  "id_expediente": "1111",
  "demandado": "Alejandra_prueba",
  "direccion": "Plan de Ayala-cdscdscds",
  "status": "Inicio",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-06-22 10:38:30",
  "tipo_juicio": "zzzzzzxxxxx"

  }
 ],//Eliminar este otro
 {
"id_expediente": "123",
"demandado": "José_prueba",
"direccion": "Plan de Ayala_pp",
"status": "Asignada",
"tipo_juicio": "xxxxxxx"
},
{
"id_expediente": "1",
"demandado": "JOSE_prueba",
"direccion": "Barlovento 1",
"status": "Asignada",
"tipo_juicio": "xxxx"
}
]
```

Comment: Acabo de correr tu codigo y funciona correctamente.

Comment: si corre correctamente, despues de esto debo enviar ese json a una base, pero no la guarda, por los corchetes que se agregaron dentro del for,  de lo contrario lo guarda, o habra alguna forma de eliminar esos corchetes despues del for ?

Comment: Me refiero a que a mi no me agrega los corchetes